# PHP date() returning different values for different users

Tags: php, iis-8

I have a problem with some users receiving different dates in my project.
The project runs under PHP 7.4 on IIS.

My Machine is in Vancouver and the users are in Brisbane Australia

I've isolated the issue to the code below:

```
$tzone = 'Australia/Brisbane';
$html  = '<br>Machine Date: '. date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$html .= '<br>TimeZone: '. $tzone;
$tnow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tzone));
$html .= '<br>Local Time: '.  $tnow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
echo $html;
```

Most users (over 100) receive the following (which is expected):

```
Machine Date: 2021-12-06 16:00:34
TimeZone: Australia/Brisbane
Local Time: 2021-12-07 10:00:34
```

However 2 get:

```
Machine Date: 2021-12-07 11:00:34
TimeZone: Australia/Brisbane
Local Time: 2021-12-07 10:00:34
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with the configuration of these users but havent been able to discover what it is. The users are set to their local timezones correctly and their clocks are set to the right time.

Comment: What is the configured [default timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) on your server? Does it change per session? Perhaps you should include it in your output above

Comment: Try to reboot server to let it regain time. Then ask users  to access again to check if issue exists.

Comment: @phil I have added a date_default_timezone_get() line to the code. For me it works correctly. I am waiting to see what the user in Australia gets. Will update when I get a response.

Comment: ok, date_default_timezone_get() returns the machine timezone of America/Vancouver on all the machines except these two, that return Australia/Melbourne (which explains the hour difference). I'm guessing a local machine override is somehow passed. I've checked their AD profile and there is no reference to Melbourne and their Machines are set to Brisbane.

Answer (score -3):

**IF YOU'RE DEVELOPING ON LOCALHOST**

There's Nothing Wrong With The Codes. The **MACHINE DATE** Displays the Users Computer Time and has nothing to do with the zone you specified.

The Local Time is affected by the zone you specified.

**Machine Date:** = Users Local Computers' Time (Not Affected By the zone you specified)

**TimeZone:** You need to specify what timezone should affect the last $html (Local Time)

**Local Time:** is influenced by the time zone you specified.

**LIVE SERVER**

On a live Server, the timezone is given by the server which you use.

Use **PHP TimeZone**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos'); // set the default timezone here to use for machine date

$tzone = 'Australia/Brisbane';
$html  = '<br>Machine Date: '. date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$html .= '<br>TimeZone: '. $tzone;
$tnow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tzone));
$html .= '<br>Local Time: '.  $tnow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Php runs on server and thus Machine Date is server generated

Comment: yeah. noted... i explained based on localhost

Comment: date() should return the date on the server that the script is running on.
It does in 100 cases. However in 2 it returns 1 hour different than the local date. Yes, I can resolve the isue with date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver'); However this is a workaround and not the solution.